# Delete 3 oldest files based on filename

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, ls, rm

I want to delete the 3 oldest files based on their filename.

Here is an example of what is in my backup directory.
There will be multiple copies with different times.

Ubuntu_Scripts.zip_2018-08-09-21

This ends up deleting all the files and not leaving the newest one or two.

```
lst=$(ls -t /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Ubuntu_Documents_*|tail -3)
for f in $lst;do if [ -f $f ];then rm -rf $f;
```

fi;done

If it would make it easier to solve this, I can generate the files in date_filename format.

Answer (score 1):

Given your filename format, a simple lexical sort should be sufficient. So for example

```
printf '%s\0' Ubuntu_Scripts.zip_* | sort -z | head -zn3 | xargs -0 echo rm --
```

The `-z` isn't necessary for your examples, but doesn't cost anything and makes the pipeline valid for any legal names (including those containing newlines).

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied it is identifying the appropriate files.

--

If `zsh` is available, you could remove the first three matching files by name ascending using built-in glob qualifiers:

```
rm -- Ubuntu_Scripts.zip_*(.on[1,3])
```

Comment: Don't think it works. andy7_~$ t.sh
sending incremental file list

sent 72 bytes  received 12 bytes  168.00 bytes/sec
total size is 29,452,416  speedup is 350,624.00
rm -- Ubuntu_Scripts.zip_*

Comment: @fixit7 that looks like a message from a file transfer program - it's hard to see any connection with the commands I wrote

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
#
# Delete all but 2 newest files in selected directory
# 

ls -1t /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1/Ubuntu_Mate_18.04/Documents_Backups/Ubuntu_Documents_* | 
# skip (leave) the 2 newest
tail -n +3 |
# delete the 3 oldest
tail -n -3 |
while IFS= read -r file
do
  rm "$file"
done   
exit 0
```